"Circle average" definition
I need (for some operations with color's hue) to define "circle average" $\kappa$.
Let we have unit circle with path parameter $0 \leq t \leq 1$.
For $t_1 = 0.2$ and $t_2 = 0.9$ $\kappa$ should be $0.05$, as intuitively clear by the image:

For $t_1 = 0.25$ and $t_2 = 0.75$ we must define the rule of choice between $\kappa = 0(1)$ or $\kappa =  0.5$:

And of course we need some definition for the arrays of $\{ t_i \}$, so that we get a result like this:

How can this definition be correctly formulated?

You could take the usual average of the given unit vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ and then renormalize the result to have length $1$. You'll still need special cases if the average comes out to $0$ - this is your "rule of choice", and it's unclear how it should generalize to averaging more than 2 inputs.

@Karl if you take averages to be over the whole color space (hue, saturation and lightness), then averages become well-defined. An average over two colors of opposing hue would be some gray-ish color of zero saturation. RGB space allows for easiest computation of averages.

Looks like polar coordinates to me.

The wikipedia page for circular mean contains an exact solution for your problem, including an example python implementation, Assuming that there are no weights:
$$\displaystyle {\bar {\alpha }}=\operatorname {atan2} \left({\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\sin \alpha _{j},{\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\cos \alpha _{j}\right)=\operatorname {atan2} \left(\sum _{j=1}^{n}\sin \alpha _{j},\sum _{j=1}^{n}\cos \alpha _{j}\right)$$ Where $\bar {\alpha }$ is the mean angle.
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_mean.
I whipped up a quick test in desmos, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kj94jvud9s, and the aforementioned formula behaves as expected.
